# 2d array Python question, range of if, elifs, one not working as expected

Tags: python, arrays, list, if-statement, 2d

I have the following program in which the user enters a number an an X is placed in the position on the matrix.

I am attempting, for teaching purposes, to solve it using selection only (at the moment).

You'll note that it works for all numbers, except 0. The last elif is for numbers less than 1 -e.g. 0. The code tells it to place the X in position 0,0, but it places it in 7 instead.

What's going on?
https://trinket.io/python/987e8c46d7

Note, I only added the last elif, because the first elif which should also deal with numbers less than 7 doesn't work. How can I deal with this using the same structure.

I want to then build on the teaching looking at the if statements and look at areas of repetition or unrequired complexity, in order to show it can be further simplified for more elegant code.

```
def matrix():
  print("---The Matrix---")
  #create a 1d array of 7 stars
  matrix1=[
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"]
  ]
  #user enters a number
  number=int(input("Enter number:"))
  #you are always finding the remainder on each row to place the X
  remainder=number%7
  
  #an 'X' is placed in the position of the number
  #remainder-1 because we start at index 0
  
  if number<=7:
    matrix1[0][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>7 and number<15:
    matrix1[1][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>14 and number<22:
    matrix1[2][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>21 and number<29:
    matrix1[3][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>28 and number<36:
    matrix1[4][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>35 and number<43:
    matrix1[5][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>42 and number<50:
    matrix1[6][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number<1:
    matrix[0][0]=="X"


  #the updated matrix is printed.
  print(matrix1)
matrix()
```

Comment: Your if-elif statements should be lowest number to highest number. Also, `matrix[0][0]` should be `matrix1[0][0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your el-if statements should be like below. In your implementation, the code goes `if number <=7` statement when user enters 0 as input number. So, `if number<1:` statement should come first.

```py
...

  if number<1:
    matrix1[0][0]="X"
  elif number<=7:
    matrix1[0][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>7 and number<15:
    matrix1[1][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>14 and number<22:
    matrix1[2][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>21 and number<29:
    matrix1[3][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>28 and number<36:
    matrix1[4][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>35 and number<43:
    matrix1[5][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>42 and number<50:
    matrix1[6][remainder-1]="X"

...
```

Comment: Tried that - and it still does not place an X in the 0th position in the 2d array. See here https://trinket.io/python/cdcba8b69d

Comment: You should `matrix1[0][0]=="X"`to `matrix1[0][0]="X"`. I edited the answer.

Comment: brilliant. I have a follow on question. Will paste here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70385478/python-simplifying-selection-statements-to-using-a-loop

Answer (score 1):

If `number < 1`, then `number <= 7`, so the first condition in your `if` statements will apply before it reaches the `number < 1` check. The remainder in that case is `0`, so it will index `matrix1[0][-1]`, which is the last item in that row. You should move the `number < 1` check to the beginning of your `if` statements to fix this. Also, I think you have a typo in that code since you're accessing `matrix` instead of `matrix1`, and you're using the `==` operator instead of an assignment.

```py
  if number < 1:
    matrix1[0][0] = "X"
  elif number<=7:
    matrix1[0][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>7 and number<15:
    matrix1[1][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>14 and number<22:
    matrix1[2][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>21 and number<29:
    matrix1[3][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>28 and number<36:
    matrix1[4][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>35 and number<43:
    matrix1[5][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>42 and number<50:
    matrix1[6][remainder-1]="X"
```

Comment: could you post a solution please

Comment: brilliant, thank you > another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70385478/python-simplifying-selection-statements-to-using-a-loop

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more simply by just using int division for the first index rather than having a bunch of `if` statements that individually map each range to the same result:

```
def matrix():
    print("---The Matrix---")
    # create a 2d array of 7x7 stars
    matrix1 = [["*" for _ in range(7)] for _ in range(7)]

    number = int(input("Enter number: "))
    matrix1[number // 7][number % 7] = "X"

    # print the matrix
    print('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in matrix1))


matrix()
```

```
---The Matrix---
Enter number: 0
X******
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
```

```
---The Matrix---
Enter number: 48
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
******X
```

If you want the user-inputted numbers to go from 1-49 instead of 0-48, just subtract 1 from `number` after the user inputs it.  You can "clip" inputs below 1 and above 49 with `min` and `max`:

```
number = int(input("Enter number: ")) - 1
number = max(number, 0)
number = min(number, 48)
```

Comment: can you explain this. For say '14'. matrix1[number // 7][number % 7] = "X"
number//7 = 2    and  number%7 = 0.   This should put the X in row 2 and position 0? ....

Comment: Exactly; `14 // 7` is `2` and `14 % 7` is `0`.  As I said, if you wanted to shift everything over so that 14 is at `matrix[1][6]` instead (which is sort of how your code works, but it has some problems around the corners), just subtract 1.

Comment: yes but matrix1[2][0] - would not be putting it in the fourteenth position? Wouldn't this be row 2 and the first element in row 2, rather than the 7th element in row 2. What am I missing please?

Comment: If you start counting from `0` (which is how most programming languages work), then `14` is the fifteenth position, not the fourteenth.  (Making it the first cell in the third row, which is `matrix1[2][0]`.)  Again: subtract 1 if you want to count from 1 instead.  :)  Your original question wasn't very clear on how exactly you wanted each number to map to a position in the matrix, or even what range of numbers is considered valid.

Comment: Samwise - brilliant BUT - note it does not work for 0

Comment: What result do you want it to have for 0?  And what result do you want it to have for 1?  Should they both be in the upper left corner, or should 0 be the corner and 1 be the spot after it?  (If you want 0 to be the same as 1, just do the -1 and add `number = max(0, number)` to clip it.  You might want to also do `number = min(number, 48)`.)

Comment: https://trinket.io/python/a19b22da26 (added your solution plus the -1) but doesn't work for 0