# Python: Simplifying selection statements to using a loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have the following code, and for teaching purposes want to go from here to simplifying it into using iteration. I want students to be able to see any repetition (e.g. the patterns) and use either a for or while loop to achieve this instead.

What would the best way to approach this be?

https://trinket.io/python/5e56cf6a5c

```
def matrix():
  print("---The Matrix---")
  #create a 1d array of 7 stars
  matrix1=[
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"]
  ]
  #user enters a number
  number=int(input("Enter number:"))
  #you are always finding the remainder on each row to place the X
  remainder=number%7
  
  #an 'X' is placed in the position of the number
  #remainder-1 because we start at index 0
  
  if number<1:
    matrix1[0][0]="X"
  elif number<=7:
    matrix1[0][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>7 and number<15:
    matrix1[1][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>14 and number<22:
    matrix1[2][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>21 and number<29:
    matrix1[3][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>28 and number<36:
    matrix1[4][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>35 and number<43:
    matrix1[5][remainder-1]="X"
  elif number>42 and number<50:
    matrix1[6][remainder-1]="X"



  #the updated matrix is printed.
  print(matrix1)
matrix()
```

Without using iteraton at all, this was suggested:

```
def matrix():
    print("---The Matrix---")
    # create a 2d array of 7x7 stars
    matrix1 = [["*" for _ in range(7)] for _ in range(7)]

    number = int(input("Enter number: "))
    matrix1[number // 7][number % 7] = "X"

    # print the matrix
    print('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in matrix1))


matrix()
```

I can't understand the following:

For say '14'. matrix1[number // 7][number % 7] = "X" number//7 = 2 and number%7 = 0. This should put the X in row 2 and position 0?

Comment: It does put 14 in `matrix1[2][0]`

Comment: Regarding your followup: the suggestion is not quite correct. You should be doing `matrix1[(number-1)//7][(number-1)%7] = 'X'`. For '14', you end up modifying position 6 of row 1.

Comment: so nearly there - but doesn't work for 0 https://trinket.io/python/a19b22da26

Comment: @Compoot Maybe I'm confused about the desired behavior. I thought that if `number` is n, then we want to change the nth entry starting from the top left to change. If that's the case, then why would we expect to receive the input '0'?

Comment: @Compoot The trinket uses Python 2. Are you working with python 2 or python 3?

Comment: @Compoot Does [this script](https://trinket.io/python3/cb551f1bad) behave correctly?

Comment: I was in Python2...quite right and well explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use any loops, but perhaps this simplification is along the lines of what you want.

```
def matrix():
  print("---The Matrix---")
  #create a 1d array of 7 stars
  matrix1=[
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
  ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"]
  ]
  #user enters a number
  number=int(input("Enter number:"))
  #you are always finding the remainder on each row to place the X
  q,r = divmod(number-1,7)
  
  matrix1[q][r] = 'X'



  #the updated matrix is printed.
  print(matrix1)
matrix()
```

Also, here's a prettier way to print that matrix.

```
for row in matrix1:
    print(*row)
```

In Python 2:

```
for row in matrix1:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

Here's a [trinket link](https://trinket.io/python3/cb551f1bad) for the Python 3 version.

Sample output:

```
---The Matrix---
Enter number:8
* * * * * * *
X * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

Comment: beautiful! .....but it doesn't work for 0

Comment: @Compoot See my other comments. What should happen if we put in 0? What is the "0th" entry? If there's a 0th entry, then why is there also a 49th entry?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `remainder-1`, as `remainder=number%7` always returns a value between 0 and 6.

```
0%7 = 0
1%7 = 1
...
6%7 = 6
7%7 = 0
```

Which solves your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use loops like this:

```
def matrix():
    print("---The Matrix---")
    #create a 1d array of 7 stars
    matrix1=[
    ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
    ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
    ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
    ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
    ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
    ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"],
    ["*","*","*","*","*","*","*"]
    ]
    #user enters a number
    number= int(float(input("Enter number:")))
    
    #you are always finding the remainder on each row to place the X
    
    #an 'X' is placed in the position of the number
    #remainder-1 because we start at index 0
    
    for i in range(1,len(matrix1)+1):
        for j in range(1,len(matrix1)+1):
            if i * j == number:
                matrix1[i-1][j-1] = "X"



    #the updated matrix is printed.
    print(matrix1)
matrix()
```

Comment: great try....nearly works but not quite. Try it with the input 2

Comment: @Compoot it still works with the input as 2 for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the use of a 2D array isn't a key part, then a better option is just to do simple replacements on a single list, and use other functions to style the output. Here we use `textwrap` to split the text into lines 7 chars long:

```
import textwrap

def matrix():
  print("---The Matrix---")
  # Create a list of '*', 49 items long
  matrix1= ["*"] * 49
  #user enters a number
  number=int(input("Enter number:"))

  # Update the list element in that position
  matrix1[number] = "X"

  #the updated matrix is printed.
  print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(''.join(matrix1), 7)))

matrix()
```

Admittedly this also means that no loops or iterations are involved, which might defeat the point of the exercise...

Answer (score 1):

It puts the 14 into Row 2 Column 0 as you said.
Your implementation have bugs. For example, 0 and 1 has same output. So, normally if you using zero indexing the suggested code is perfect.

When we give 14 for your implementation, it assumes it is in Row 1 because of the el-if statements. `matrix1[1][remainder-1]`becomes `matrix1[1][-1]` then it puts X to last element of row. The -1 functionality of python shows like your implementation is correct. But it is not.

The suggested implementation is correct if you using zero indexing. If you say it should start 1, so your loopy implementation is also wrong.